# Changes when record was created in today extension and updated in app are not visible in today extension

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

Simply I have an app, and today extension. Also I have two entities: **Goal** and **Service**.

```
@objc(Goal)
class Goal: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var identifier: String
    @NSManaged var startDate: Date
    @NSManaged var endDate: Date

    private var services: [Service] {
    
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ && date <= %@", startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)

        return Service.mr_findAll(with: predicate) as! [Service]
    }

    var duration: Int64 {
        return services.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.duration }
    }
}
```

When I create `service` related to `goal` in **today extension** and update it within an app, updated results are not visible in today extension while are displayed properly in an app. Why?

This is how I create and update record in an extension or in an extension:

```
MagicalRecord.save({ context in
        
    Service.createOrUpdate(withDuration: duration, date: Date(), identifier: identifier, in: context)
        
}, completion: { _, error in
        
        //do something on completion
})
```

Comment: can you provide code where you perform changes? Also why are you using `NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default().fetch(fetchRequest)` instead of `self.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)`

Comment: should I use self? Always the same context?

Comment: IMHO you should use self but I can't tell in 100% because I don't know how you use this class. The contexts don't necessarily have to be the same, if so then it's no problem but otherwise in some cases app can even crash.

Comment: ok I will let you know later... how I make changes...

Comment: `viewContext.refreshAllObjects()` is working perfectly for me. I am calling this code in `onAppear{}` of swiftui

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension and the app are different programs that share some of the same code.  So both are creating their **own** persistentStoreCoordinator and context(s).

Normally in the same app you would have multiple context all attached to the same persistentStoreCoordinator and changes in one would be handled by the notifications that are sent out via notificationCenter and then merged.  In this case there are two problems - 1) notificationCenter is not shared between the app and the extension so they can't communicate easily and 2) the context don't share the same `persistentStoreCoordinator` so you can't use 'mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` even if you did pass that information.

I haven't tried this before, but this is what I would try:

1. setup some way to trigger that a change occurred. There are many solutions to this.
2. setup your `managedObjectContext`(s) to have a `stalenessInterval` of 0
3. when there is a change you have to update your core data.  You can do this by calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` on all your core data object, or do another fetch. The trick is that you have to have the context fetch from the store and the store to fetch from the file, and not hit any of the caches in the between.

Comment: I know that app and extension are completely separate apps. But database is shared between them. Now I create entity in app extension, and then I update it within an app (app can see just created entity by extension). But changes made by app are not visible to an extension. Why? What exactly should I do to fix this? I did call `refreshObject:mergeChanges` within an app after I updated record, but it didnt work. I do not understand `managedObjectContext` and `stalenessInterval`. Where should I set it?

Comment: ok, I did it. I just fetched objects. Refresh them, and then fetched again. It worked.

Comment: Thank you. I will award bounty for you tomorrow:)

Answer (score 2):

Base on @JonRose answer the final solution for my problem was:

fetch records I am interested in, refresh them in **the same context where I did fetch them from**, and fetch them again:

```
private var services: [Service] {

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ && date <= %@", startDate as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)

    for service in Service.mr_findAll(with: predicate, in: NSManagedObjectContext.mr_rootSaving())! {
        NSManagedObjectContext.mr_rootSaving().refresh(service, mergeChanges: false)
    }

    return Service.mr_findAll(with: predicate) as! [Service]
}
```

Comment: Just stumbled upon this same issue while trying to reload data on my main app when items are added from SiriKit. Ended up I need to fetch again, and refresh. Interesting enough just one fetch or one refresh would not pick up the changes that are performed via SiriKit! This seems like quite a hack.